# Get response code from Sqlite3 using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

## CASE

What i need:
1. INSERT OR IGNORE (COL1 has UNIQUE constraint)
2. Get Sqlite3 response code to check if row was inserted or ignored.
3. If row was ignored, print row. Else continue.

## Code

`query = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO MYTABLE (COL1,COL2) VALUES ('VAL1', 'VAL2');"
db.execute(query)`

Im thinking something like this:

```
response_code = db.execute(query)
if "insert" in response code:
continue
elif "ignore" in response_code
print(row)
```

Comment: It isn't possible to do a select and insert at the same time.  Have you tried yet what you are suggesting?

Comment: Yeah. I don't see fitting options in the object. I can solve this somehow, but i'm trying to be efficient reducing IO. So i would try to avoid searching for VAL1 before doing insert or ignore.

Comment: You might have to do this inside a transaction.  Do you really need the duplicate record?

Comment: So far i just solved this by 1. "select * from" and if len(rows) < 0 insert >

Comment: There is no such response code.